# How to make double tap and panning work at same time, in Android?

Tags: android, touch-event, double-click, panning

So I'm trying to get my view working with many different ways, there should be:

- Multitouch for zooming
- Touchlistener for panning
- Doubleclick for restoring zoom
- or if it's already restored it will zoom the place where double click was.

At the moment, everything else is working but when I doubleclick and keep second click down and continue moving it the code is working that way it first `restores/zooms` and then `panning starts`.

So because of zoomscale, it will sometimes first change the size of canvas and then start panning. What should I do to enable panning after double click noticed? Or something like check if double click's last click keeps moving and skip the zoom/restore thing? My code looks like this atm. And I am trying to return false after doubleclick but it doesnt really effect... Would there be something like setting `ignoreMultiTouch` to `true`, but on double click or panning?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(mgestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)){
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();

        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray);

        ev.setLocation(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                // Save the ID of this pointer
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;


                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;
                mTranslateMatrix.preTranslate(dx, dy);
                mTranslateMatrix.invert(mTranslateMatrixInverse);

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                normal = false;

                invalidate();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;

            }
        }
    }
    return true;

}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        if (detector.isInProgress()) {
            mFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
            mFocusY = detector.getFocusY();
        }
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.75f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 3.0f));
        mScaleMatrix.setScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                mFocusX, mFocusY);
        mScaleMatrix.invert(mScaleMatrixInverse);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();

        return true;
    }
}

private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    // event when double tap occurs
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        if (!normal) {
            restore();
        } else {
            zoomToSpot(e);
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made my code working with these little things, first I added the doubleclicked boolean

```
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        if (!normal) {
            restore();
        } else {
            zoomToSpot(e);
        }
        doubleclicked = true;
        return true;
    }
```

then I made two different onTouchEvents and set the first only working if doubleclicked is false. The second one will set doubleclicked false when there is no fingers left on screen.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    final int action = ev.getAction();

    if (!doubleclicked) {
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                //something...
        }
    } else {
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                doubleclicked = false;
                break;
            }
         }
     }
```